# applying jquery code to more than one class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I have this little snippet of code applied to only one class

```
function replaceSF(foo,bar)
{
j$('.labelCol').children().each(function(){ 
    console.log('i am on children each for labelCol');
    console.log('foo: '+foo);
    console.log('bar: '+bar);
    console.log('jsthis.text: '+j$(this).text());
    if(j$(this).text() == foo)
    {      
        j$(this).html(''+bar);    
    }
    else if(j$(this).text().trim().replace('\*','').replace('\n','') == foo)
    {
        j$(this).html(j$(this).html().replace(foo,''+bar));
    }
    });  
    j$('.labelCol').each(function(){   
    if(j$(this).text() == foo )
    {      
        j$(this).html(''+bar);   
    }
    }); 
}
```

but I need to use this code for like 10 classes. What's the best approach to do this?
I was trying to rewrite this function as `replaceSF(className,foo,bar)` but I didn't get any results.

Thanks.

Comment: You should post the code where you tried "to rewrite this function as `replaceSF(className,foo,bar)`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your selector to something like:

```
j$('.labelCol, .labelCol2, .labelCol3, .labelCol4, .labelColn').children().each(function(){
```

...

Comment: i.e. you can write the jQuery selector like you would a CSS rule.

Answer (score 2):

Add more classes like below

```
j$('.labelCol,.anotherclassname,.anotherclassname1').children().each(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

To write the function as you say you'd like, you could take the approach:

```
function replaceSF(arrayOfClassNames,foo,bar){
    j$('.' + arrayOfClassNames.join(', .')).children() /* and so on… */

    /* which would form the CSS-style selector:
    j$('.labelCol, .secondClassName, .anotherClassName').children()
    */
}
```

Calling the function as:

```
replaceSF(['labelCol','secondClassName', 'anotherClassName'], 'foo', 'bar');
```